array return [object Object] on any kind of interaction, if returned from a class why?
Intro
I'm currently trying to get to know how spa commonly work, router, state, route etc,
I've done a basic hash router and can display on a fragment element, and now trying to introduce a custom react like component, but arrived to placeholder {{ }} replacement, I've been stuck for days on an error which, even if I've found a work around, still do not even begin to understand. it seems like if returned from within class constructor i cannot use [...].join("") or [...][1] without it to interpreted as [object Object]
Code & How it happened
In order not to interfere with nested component i settled for a DFS through child Node of my component
and delegated the parsing to a sub class, the specific condition handling that being :
      if (current && current?.getAttribute) {
          current.innerHTML = new _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser({ node: current, content: current.innerHTML })
      }

in the _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser

class _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser {

    constructor({ node, content }) {
         this.node = node;

         return this.placeholderParser(content);
    }

     placeholderParser(value) {
        if(value.trim === "") {
            return value
        }
        
        const parts = value.split(/(<\/?\w+[^>]*>)/g);

        const stack = [];
        let output = [];

        for (let part of parts) {
            const trimmedPart = part.trim();

            if (/^<\w+[^>]*>$/.test(trimmedPart)) {
                stack.push(trimmedPart);
                const processedTag =
                    stack.length === 1
                        ? trimmedPart.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g, "testing")
                        : trimmedPart;

                output.push(String(processedTag));

                if (this.isSelfClosing(trimmedPart)) {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            } else if (/^<\/\w+>$/.test(trimmedPart)) {
                stack.pop();
                output.push(String(trimmedPart));
            } else if (/\{\{.*?\}\}/.test(trimmedPart) && stack.length === 0) {
                output.push(String(trimmedPart.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g, "testing")));
            } else if (trimmedPart.length > 0) {
                output.push(String(trimmedPart));
            }
        }

        return output.join("");
    }

//rest of the method ...
}

To come to where my problem pops up, it's in the _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser. This class directly returns
this.placeholderParser(), which itself returns output.join("").
Except, on the DOM, output.join("") says [object Object] even though, when logged during the process,
it contains the parsed data that should be returned.
For proof, if instead I return simply output, it shows perfectly as an array in the DOM, comma-separated.
So output.join("") shouldn't be a problem, right?
And also, it's not only .join.
If I try output[0], it also says [object Object], so building a string out of output by hand doesn't work—it'll just return [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]....
And don't even think my logic has anything to do with that—I cut it out and replaced output with ["test", "it works"].
It did the exact same thing, even when I did nothing to the array. The values were hardcoded and directly returned, but it behaved the same way. Just why?
What's happening here?
It only works if I return output directly and do the joining from my DFS condition as:
if (current && current?.getAttribute) {
    current.innerHTML = new _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser({ node: current, content: current.innerHTML }).join("")
}

What I Need Help With

Why does output.join("") return [object Object] in the DOM when returned from the class?
Is this related to how JavaScript handles the return value of a class constructor?
What’s the proper way to fix this issue?


Why is _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser even a class in the first place and not just a function? You don't seem to need the class instance anywhere.

@gre_gor, in order to debug more easily it had to be a class, so that i can decouple and log what's happening in my code, the method use for it kinda grow to fast so i had to do a custom _Fa_debughelper, that take a ref of the object and can on demand log as console.log, while keeping track of where the log came from

the issue arises since new SomeClass always returns an Object, regardless of what the constructor returns this could be an instance of the class, or another Object - returning a String from the constructor results in an instance of the class being returned
Try the following:
class _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser {

    constructor({ node, content }) {
        this.node = node;
        this.content = content;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.placeholderParser(this.content);
    }
    // ... the rest is unchanged

edit: based on the comment by gre_gor
class _Fo_Component_PlaceholderParser {

    constructor({ node, content }) {
         this.node = node;

         return new String(this.placeholderParser(content));
    }

Would be a better solution

"returning a String from the constructor results in an instance of the class being returned" This is not true.

@gre_gor - thank you for incorrecting me .. new String returns an instance of a String (i.e. an object), not a primitive - but I see how the code could be written different :p

@gre_gor Your example shows exactly what @Bravo is claiming to be true. Also, I tested it myself and it is indeed true (at least for Chrome and Node). Note that it is said that returning a String (which is as a literal string or a literal string in a variable) will make the constructor return its own class instance. If you wish to return a string from a constructor, then it must be a String instance, like your example shows.

@KLASANGUI - gre_gor's comment does imply a better solution (see edit)

thanks to you guys, I. the provided solution indeed works.

so @Bravo, @gre_gor if i get this right, the constructor method was meant to return an object not a non-primitive value, so directly doing so is ignored by javascript, whom decide to return this object instead, in  order to bypass this fact we just have follow the rule and return an object, so something akin to constructor (){ return {message: this.placeolderParse } } works but constructor (){ return "direct string" } doesn't
